# Is there possible to put more than one radial-gradient in a div

Tags: html, css

I need to show a div with to radial-gradient something like this:

[image: I need this]

I have this area in a div like this:

```
<div class="ticketInfo">
  <div class="itemInfo">
    <h6 class="colorBlack">AREA</h6>
    <h5 class="colorBlack">{{ticketSelected.location}}</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="itemInfo">
    <h6 class="colorBlack">DOORS</h6>
    <h5 class="colorBlack">{{ticketSelected.date}}</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="itemInfo">
    <h6 class="colorBlack">DEPART</h6>
    <h5 class="colorBlack">{{ticketSelected.time}}</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I write this one in my css:

```
.ticketInfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -2% 103%, $mainBackground 14px, white 15px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 103%, $mainBackground 14px, white 15px);
  padding: 13px;
}
```

But in that way I only have the first one, the left one, but the right one I can't show.

I need help! Thanks!!

Comment: Please add to your question: [mcve]

Comment: @IvankaTodorova great job...

Comment: I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white color of the first gradient is over the second one, you have to set `transparent` to see the second gradient that is below.

```css
.radial {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -2% 103%, red 14px, transparent 15px), radial-gradient(circle at 100% 103%, blue 14px, white 15px);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radial"></div>
```